# How to backup on premise data to AWS S3 bucket using tool/service?

Tags: amazon-s3

Let me explain a little bit, we are keeping users data to a centralized Share folder(*Configured on Domain Controller, permission set via NTFS & Security group*), like M-Marketing, S-Sales & T-Trading, etc(*These drives are mapped to windows login profile according to their work profile*).

On-premise back is already configured. Now I want to back up some of the important drives (Like M, S, T) to `AWS S3` to keep data safe & whenever is Source data is not available for whatever reason, I must be able to map those drives according to their work profile.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: You can configure use AWSCLI and configure a cronjob that would run on intervals to backup your data on s3 bucket.

Comment: What backup software are you currently using? Does it know how to work with cloud services? What is your backup policy (eg how often to backup, time to recover)? Feel free to edit your question to add these details.